# Eclipse project build takes a long time

Tags: eclipse

I'm working with a decent sized application (300-350MBs) in my Eclipse IDE. All is well, but when I modify a source file (i.e. `MyServlet.java`), I can't see any changes until I clean the project, which in turn runs a project build. Due to the size of my project, this build takes about 3-5 minutes.

I guess what I'm asking is if there's a faster way to update changes made to my source files, so that whenever I need to debug, I don't have to wait 5 minutes for every minor change.

What I've tried so far:

- Restarting the server
- Refreshing the project
- Restarting Eclipse
- Committing to the SVN
- Clearing my browser cache

Comment: use IntelliJ IDEA :) Eclipse has very poor indexing, thus you must wait forever until it refreshes

Comment: [Building](http://xkcd.com/303/)

Comment: +1 for the comic lololol

Comment: Do you have `Project > Build automatically` selected?

Comment: No I unselected that early on

Answer (score 3):

There is a dedicated tool for that: JRebel. Problem is that you need a licence.

But what you really need to do is to recompile changed class. In your case if this is a Servlet you also need to deploy it to server (+some servers support 'hot-deploy' and some don't,  I.e. do you have to restart the server)